# SQL Server joining results condition

Tags: sql-server, join, case

I have table:

```
NAME    FACTOR
say_type1    A
(...)
say_type2    B
(...)
say_type3    A
(...)
say_type3    B
```

I would like to get as result of an answer (SELECT name, factor FROM... WHERE some_condition):

```
say_type1    A
say_type2    B
say_type3    A,B
```

Im trying CASE but it acts always only for one record.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concat"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to convert FACTOR column into row. You can make it with [XML PATH](https://sqlservergujarat.blogspot.ru/2009/07/for-xml-path-how-to-generate-delimited.html):

```
--F.e. we have this in YourTable
--('say_type1', 'A'),
--('say_type2', 'B'),
--('say_type3', 'A'),
--('say_type3', 'B')

SELECT DISTINCT t1.NAME,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + FACTOR
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE NAME = t1.NAME
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as FACTOR
FROM YourTable t1
```

Output:

```
NAME        FACTOR
say_type1   A
say_type2   B
say_type3   A,B
```